# Computing the Euclidean distances between corresponding rows of matrices with CUDA

Tags: cuda, parallel-processing, gpu

I have a very simple algorithm that computes the squared Euclidean distances between the corresponding rows of two matrices. I have the following code but unfortunately it does not return the correct results for different matrix sizes. More specifically, it works fine for matrices of size `2000x4`, `500x4`, `2500x2`, `600x8`, `1000x8`, `100x8` but it is not working for a matrix of size`2500x3`, `2500x5`, `400x3`, `100x3`, `100x10`, `1000x10`, `1000x12`, `500x12`, `500x14`.

Can anybody help me? I want to do it manually, without using any optimized library, because I want to understand thread management.

```
__global__ void cudaEuclid( float* A, float* B, float* C, int rows, int cols )
    {
        int i, squareeucldist = 0;
        int r = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x; // rows
        int c = blockDim.y * blockIdx.y + threadIdx.y; // cols 
        extern __shared__ float sdata[];
        //int r = blockIdx.y; int c = threadIdx.x;
        if( r < rows && c < cols  ){

            //C[r + rows*c] = ( A[r + rows*c] - B[r + rows*c] ) * ( A[r + rows*c] - B[r + rows*c] );


            sdata[threadIdx.x] = ( A[r + rows*c] - B[r + rows*c] ) * ( A[r + rows*c] - B[r + rows*c] );

            __syncthreads();

            // contiguous range pattern
            for(int offset = blockDim.x / 2;
                offset > 0;
                offset >>= 1)
            {
                if(threadIdx.x < offset)
                {
                    // add a partial sum upstream to our own
                    sdata[threadIdx.x] += sdata[threadIdx.x + offset];
                }

                // wait until all threads in the block have
                // updated their partial sums
                __syncthreads();
            }

            // thread 0 writes the final result
            if(threadIdx.x == 0)
            {
                C[r] = sdata[0];
            }

        }

    }
```

The kernel call is:

```
dim3 dimBlock( cols, 1 ); 
dim3 dimGrid( 1, rows ); 
cudaEuclid<<<dimGrid, cols, cols*sizeof(float)>>>( d_A, d_B, d_C, rows, cols );
```

**PS**: I want to mention that I had posted a similar question but it was unclear from the beginning and the discussion was disoriented. Even though Tom made a very useful suggestion that it will be very practical in future for optimized implementations, I need something more handmade. Finally, the reason I made this post is because I do not want to make the related post more complicated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tested 60x8 or did you stop at 60x5?  Odd columns don't seem to be handled correctly.  Or maybe even non powers of 2 given `offset >>=1`...

Comment: It is working for 60x8.

Comment: Makes sense, well that's the problem, although Eric gave a complete answer.

Comment: More examples added if that matters in any case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact your code works only on `m * 2^n` when `n` is small enough. You probably want to read more carefully about the following slides on page 14,

http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/samples/6_Advanced/reduction/doc/reduction.pdf

and think about the following questions

1. what will happen when your `blockDim.x` is equal to 3 or 5;
2. how the parallel reduction could be correctly done when `blockDim.x` or `cols` is not a power of 2;
3. why the reduction result is smaller than expected;
4. which element(s) in `sdata[]` is not added to the final sum;
5. will the result be correct if you set `blockDim.x` and size of smem to 2^3 when `cols` is 5;
6. in the case of q5, how to deal with the extra 3 element space in `smem[5..7]`

Try to simulate running the for loop step by step with your pen and paper will help.

Comment: I was updating the post while your are giving the answer. By the way yes it is not working on 60x3.

Comment: You only need to add a few lines to deal with the cases when cols is not a pow of 2.

Answer (score 1):

Although the OP does not want to use optimized libraries to answer his question, the post has a useful title and other users can find it useful to solve the problem without handwritten kernels.

I was curious and played a bit with the problem, having in mind to use CUDA Thrust. I ended up with the code below, which calculates the distances between homologous rows of two matrices by using `thrust::reduce_by_key`.

```
#include <thrust\device_vector.h>
#include <thrust\transform_reduce.h>
#include <thrust\sequence.h>
#include <thrust\random.h>
#include <thrust\gather.h>
#include <thrust\extrema.h>

using namespace thrust::placeholders;

/****************************************************/
/* POWER DIFFERENCE FUNCTOR FOR EUCLIDEAN DISTANCES */
/****************************************************/
struct PowerDifference {
    __host__ __device__ float operator()(const float& a, const float& b) const { return pow(a - b, 2); }
};

/*******************/
/* EXPAND OPERATOR */
/*******************/
template <typename InputIterator1, typename InputIterator2, typename OutputIterator>
OutputIterator expand(InputIterator1 first1,
                      InputIterator1 last1,
                      InputIterator2 first2,
                      OutputIterator output)
{
    typedef typename thrust::iterator_difference<InputIterator1>::type difference_type;

    difference_type input_size  = thrust::distance(first1, last1);
    difference_type output_size = thrust::reduce(first1, last1);

    // scan the counts to obtain output offsets for each input element
    thrust::device_vector<difference_type> output_offsets(input_size, 0);
    thrust::exclusive_scan(first1, last1, output_offsets.begin()); 

    // scatter the nonzero counts into their corresponding output positions
    thrust::device_vector<difference_type> output_indices(output_size, 0);
    thrust::scatter_if(thrust::counting_iterator<difference_type>(0), thrust::counting_iterator<difference_type>(input_size),
                       output_offsets.begin(), first1, output_indices.begin());

    // compute max-scan over the output indices, filling in the holes
    thrust::inclusive_scan(output_indices.begin(), output_indices.end(), output_indices.begin(), thrust::maximum<difference_type>());

    // gather input values according to index array (output = first2[output_indices])
    OutputIterator output_end = output; thrust::advance(output_end, output_size);
    thrust::gather(output_indices.begin(), output_indices.end(), first2, output);

    // return output + output_size
    thrust::advance(output, output_size);

    return output;
}

/********/
/* MAIN */
/********/
int main()
{
    /**************************/
    /* SETTING UP THE PROBLEM */
    /**************************/

    const int N     = 10;           // --- Number of vector elements
    const int Nvec  = 20;           // --- Number of vectors for each matrix

    // --- Random uniform integer distribution between 0 and 100
    thrust::default_random_engine rng;
    thrust::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0, 20);

    // --- Matrix allocation and initialization
    thrust::device_vector<float> d_matrix1(Nvec * N);
    thrust::device_vector<float> d_matrix2(Nvec * N);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < d_matrix1.size(); i++) d_matrix1[i] = (float)dist(rng);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < d_matrix2.size(); i++) d_matrix2[i] = (float)dist(rng);

    printf("\n\nFirst matrix\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < Nvec; i++) {
        std::cout << " [ ";
        for(int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            std::cout << d_matrix1[i * N + j] << " ";
        std::cout << "]\n";
    }

    printf("\n\nSecond matrix\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < Nvec; i++) {
        std::cout << " [ ";
        for(int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            std::cout << d_matrix2[i * N + j] << " ";
        std::cout << "]\n";
    }

    /****************************************************************************/
    /* CALCULATING THE EUCLIDEAN DISTANCES BETWEEN THE ROWS OF THE TWO MATRICES */
    /****************************************************************************/
    // --- Creating the indices for the reduction by key
    thrust::device_vector<int> d_sequence(Nvec);
    thrust::device_vector<int> d_indices(Nvec * N);
    thrust::device_vector<int> d_counts(Nvec, N);
    thrust::sequence(d_sequence.begin(), d_sequence.begin() + Nvec);
    expand(d_counts.begin(), d_counts.end(), d_sequence.begin(), d_indices.begin());

    printf("\n\nSecond matrix\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < Nvec; i++) {
        std::cout << " [ ";
        for(int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            std::cout << d_indices[i * N + j] << " ";
        std::cout << "]\n";
    }

    thrust::device_vector<float> d_squared_differences(Nvec * N);

    thrust::transform(d_matrix1.begin(), d_matrix1.end(), d_matrix2.begin(), d_squared_differences.begin(), PowerDifference());

    thrust::device_vector<float> d_norms(Nvec);
    thrust::reduce_by_key(d_indices.begin(), d_indices.end(), d_squared_differences.begin(), d_indices.begin(), d_norms.begin());

    printf("\n\ndnorms\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < Nvec; i++) {
            std::cout << d_norms[i] << " ";
    }

    return 0; 
}
```